# Htaccess - restrict access to file but only in present directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have index.php file that i want to allow access only for specific ip with htaccess.

However i want to allow access for files named index.php in subdiectories for everyone.

How should I write rule that would affect only index.php in present directory? This is what i tried but with no success, it blocks index.php in subdirectories too:

```
 <Files "./index.php">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.24.2
    </Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a .htaccess inside the subdirectories which contained the Allow from all, thus allowing access to those specific directories, and subdirectories from them onwards.